# Eclipse cdt debugger only step through dessembly code and not my own

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt, breakpoints

Recently I asked a question and one of the guys here really tore into me about not using a debugger. Someone else was nice and suggested Visual Studio C++. I have been trying to work with it and it was really nice until I tried more complex code.

So I decided to try eclipse since that is the IDE I prefer. I got through the missing .gde file problem.

Now the debugger opens but It is only debugging assembly code files. This does me no good if it is not stepping through my own code.

It does not even get to my breakpoints or my code.

It don't help me to step through code I didn't write.

I really hope someone can help with this.

So the question is simple :

How to get Eclipse CDT to Debug my code I write and to stop and recognize breakpoints???
Below pic is what I am getting.

[image]

Comment: Do You compile it with -g or -ggdb flag? If yes, did you choose binary compiled with debug symbols in debug configuration? It seems that You are trying to debug binary without debug information.

Comment: I think gdb. I am completely new to the debugger so am trying to figure everything out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally just went with Visual studio, not my choice but it work better than the others for a debugger.